# Mirroring a private nuget repository with AWS Code Artifact

Tags: nuget, aws-codeartifact

In our project, we are using a few sources of Nuget packages

1. nuget.org
2. our packages repository
3. third-party repository that has stability issues

Once we are using AWS I was wondering whether we can move to the Code Artifact repository. Did yu find a way to:

1. connect to the third-party private repository
2. setup a retention policy to delete not-used packages automatically?